# What is the epsilon neighborhood of a circle mean?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not sure, but I'm being asked to describe the set of points that are in this neighborhood of a circle with radius r. here is the only thing I can think of ...which is the equation of a circle with epsilons added to the y...It seems incorrect.

Comment: I believe it means the union of all $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods at each point of the circle.

Comment: Can you precisely describe what you mean? It sounds like you have a circle, say $C=\{ x : \| x \| = c \}$ and your neighborhood of the circle is $N=\{ x : (\exists y \in C) \: d(x,y) < \varepsilon \}$. Provided $\varepsilon$ is positive and sufficiently small, this is an annulus.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a circle is $$x^2+y^2=r^2.$$ Now you want points that are at most $\epsilon$ away from any points on the circle: they have the form $(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)$ with $(x,y)$ lying on the circle and $\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2<\epsilon^2$.

Finally, this implies that $$(r-\epsilon)^2<(x+\Delta x)^2+(y+\Delta y)^2<(r+\epsilon)^2,$$
because $$(x+\Delta x)^2+(y+\Delta y)^2 =x^2+y^2 +  \Delta x^2+\Delta y^2 + 2x\Delta x+2y\Delta y,$$and by Cauchy-Bunyakowski-Shwartz inequality $$r\epsilon<|x\Delta x+ y\Delta y|< r\epsilon.$$

Comment: OP: not sure I follow this answer, but the conclusion is: your neighborhood $N$ (provided $0<\varepsilon\le r,$ as commented above by Ian) is:$$\{(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2\mid r-\varepsilon<\sqrt{u^2+v^2}<r+\varepsilon\}.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval Indeed it is!

Comment: Yes I know. This comment was just intended to help  readers of your answer (including the OP).